# Algorithm combinations of words in a Sentence

Tags: java, string

I'm testing an algorithm for generating combinations of a sentence Using  Backtracking, for example "orange is sweet" combinations "orange is sweet, is orange sweet, sweet is orange, orange sweet is"....
[source geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-all-possible-permutations-of-words-in-a-sentence)

**Algorithm**

```java
    public static void calculatePermutations(String sentence)
    {
        // Stores all words in the sentence
        String[] lis = sentence.split(" ");
 
        // Stores all possible permutations
        // of words in this list
        List<String[]> permute = new ArrayList<>();
 
        // Generate all permutations of words
        generatePermutations(lis, 0, permute);
 
        // Iterate over all permutations
        for (String[] i : permute) {
            // Print the words in the
            // list separated by spaces
            System.out.println(String.join(" ", i));
        }
    }
 
    // Function to generate all permutations using
    // backtracking
    public static void generatePermutations(String[] arr, int index, List<String[]> permute)                        
    {
        // Base case: If the current index is equal to the
        // length of the array add the current permutation
        // to the list of permutations
        if (index == arr.length) {
            permute.add(Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length));
            return;
        }
 
        // Iterate over the remaining words and generate
        // permutations
        for (int i = index; i < arr.length; i++) {
            // Swap the current word with the ith word
            String temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[index];
            arr[index] = temp;
 
            // Make a recursive call to generate
            // permutations with the updated list and index
            generatePermutations(arr, index + 1, permute);
 
            // Swap back the current word with the
            // previously swapped word
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[index];
            arr[index] = temp;
        }
    }
 
    // Driver Code
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String sentence = "sky is blue";
        calculatePermutations(sentence);
    }
```

The algorithm is doing the combinations well, but for a large volume of data it breaks

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3481)
```

CopyOf arrays always generate a new instance so I think that's the problem

```java
   public static <T,U> T[] copyOf(U[] original, int newLength, Class<? extends T[]> newType) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T[] copy = ((Object) newType == (Object) Object[].class)
            ? (T[]) new Object[newLength]
            : (T[]) Array.newInstance(newType.getComponentType(), newLength);

        System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0,
                         Math.min(original.length, newLength));

        return copy;
    }
```

The biggest problem with this algorithm for a high processing volume, for example in my test was with more than 1 million phrases to generate combinations, would it be because it is recursive? What would be an alternative?

Comment: have you tried to increase the memory allocated for the jvm? its not exactly solution but can help a bit. anyway, unrestrained use of recursion may cause stackoverflow - so, please exercise caution.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I didn't increase the memory because it wouldn't be an alternative for our scenario. So I'm thinking that this recursive algorithm would not be an option to solve this problem. I wanted to check other alternatives

Comment: the cause for your out of memory error was.. you keep creating `Array`s which takes **contiguous** memory space. if its a `List` then jvm can sacrifice a bit of speed to sequeeze them around the `heap`. however, they can't do much if the memory space not wide enough.

Comment: Yeah, I think recursion here is not a good idea to go with. Now I wanted to see other possibilities without recursion

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the memory problem is caused by the number of arrays you have to copy and store. If it was a recursion problem, you would get StackOferflowError instead.
So in order to mitigate the current `Java heap space` issue, you could try to:

1. increase heap size via JVM memory setting (`-Xmx<size>`, e.g. `java -Xmx6g program`)
2. refactor the code in a way that it does not need to store all combinations in memory simultaneously (e.g. instead of saving a copy of an array, print or write it to a file)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I need at the end to have a Map<String, List<String>> with the phrase and its combinations. Growing the heap would not be a good option because over time we would have to grow if the volume grows. So I'm trying to identify a better approach to have the final result in a Map<String, List<String>> with the phrase and its combinations

Comment: Please note that regardless of the approach/algorithm applied, your bottleneck may be the size of the final result. Especially when the number of permutations grows rapidly - **n!**. To prove that, you could try to copy just one permutation n! times and add them to the list and check if OOM occurs.

Comment: Yes, it would be a good test. I will store the same permutation throughout the loop and check if the OOM occurs. Thanks